# Checking between time range

Tags: javascript

On my database I have a field of start time and end time, some goes overnight so it would look like 20:00 - 05:00 and some are 01:00 - 13 :00

Are there any built in function on this on jQuery? I've been having problems with nested ifs on this one.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: You're asking about times, but really they can be considered dates (today).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both values to timestamps and act on them

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Please see [answer].